# Best way to handle background process

Tags: android, notifications, listener, broadcastreceiver

I got my first android phone since two week
And I'm starting my first real App.
My phone is a LG Optimus 2X and one of the missing thing is a
notification led for when there is a missed call, sms, email ect ...

So I'm wondering what's the best way to do this.

For know I've a broatcastreceiver for incoming sms, and the I call a
service that will light the phone buttons (don't bother about this
part, it's working).
But seems that this method will workin only for sms, phone calls, not
emails.

So know I'm thinking to used Listeners instead for everything, but
this mean having a service running  nonstop. Not sure it's the best
way ...

I hope I'm clear, and that my ennglish is not too bad.
Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

I will be interested in knowing how you implement your listener framework for email notification. But I digress. If you want to have a background service, then the best way to do is polling. If you keep your service running in the background, the service becomes a prime candidate for android to kill, if it runs low on resource. But polling may not work for you, if you are trying to leverage existing email client in android. ( As I understand, you need to keep a listener running when the email message is received..)

So the best bet is to have a polling service using AlarmManager and writing your own custom email client code ( NO need for a UI). In periodic intervals you can poll your email server to check if there are new emails and then call the android inbuild email client as a pending Intent. I assume there could be some logistic problems in implementing this. ( For eg: You poll the email client, but when you notify user and the user responds to notification, you will open the android email client and that would still not have the new email, so it might confuse the users), but this is what I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the BuzzBox SDK. It has a scheduler that you can configure with a cron string and a simple notification api. You can also add to your app the integrated settings UI that include vibration, blinking and disabling during night time.
Check out: http://hub.buzzbox.com